# group by / distinct mysql vs javascript filter performance

Tags: javascript, mysql

Say I have a many to many relationship and when I query the db for the left table using a join from the right table I get duplicates because of this many to many relationship. I can use group by on the primary key to get rid of these in mysql or distinct.

However I've been told that distinct & group by are not good re:performance. With that said, I would also assume mysql performance would be better than javascript performance.

Should I be filtering my results in javascript or use group by in mysql? Any reason why one would be faster than the other?

Comment: As pointed by @Rushed this largery depends on the scenario you are facing. Generally speaking when i face many-to-many relations i always try to implement a third table of relations in order to avoid complications with distinct/group by...

Answer (score 1):

### it depends on how much data and how many concurrent users:

- if the data is reasonably low and not much concurrent users then mysql group by/distinct is the best solution.
- if the data is reasonably low and high concurrent users then Javascript filtering is the best solution here.
- if the data is large regardless of how many concurrent users then you should look for another solution than just group by/distinct and I'm not talking about filtering in javascript because in this case the huge data will cause low performance in user's browser.